# how to encode 25fps

Tags: python, ffmpeg

i am not a programmer, but a part of my  job is recoding. The person befor me left a script that recodes videos.
THE CURRENT PROBLEM: i need to add to the script the line to recode any video to 25 fps. I tried adding  -filter:v fps=fps=25 to the script and it works BUT it ignores all other recoding settings. So i would be very happy if someone could help. Sorry for my trivial language, as i said -  i am not a programmer :(
HERE IS THE SCRIPT:

```
import os, subprocess


DIR = r"\\server-01\E\_NEW CONTENT\_Current Time\Actual Programs" 


EXP = r"\\server-01\D\_RENDERED CONTENT\Current Time" 
print ( "=-===-=-=-="  )

ALLDIR =  os.listdir(DIR)
#ext = ".mp4"
#ext = ".mov"
ext = ".mpg"

FL0 = [x for x in ALLDIR if x.endswith("mpg") or x.endswith("mp4") or x.endswith("mxf") or x.endswith("mov") ]


CL = len(FL0)
print ( "Amount of files: ", CL )



#if pres_scaler
#Deint = True
Deint = False 
crop = False
#crop = True
scale = True
#scale = False
#recode = False
recode = True
interlaced_tff = False
cmdlist = []

for i in range(0, CL):
#for i in range(0, 1):
#for i in range(12, CL):
    vfs = []

cur_name = FL0[i]
print ("Input file path: ", cur_name)

new_name = os.path.splitext(cur_name)[0] + ".mp4"
PATH = DIR + os.sep + cur_name

EXPATH = EXP + os.sep + new_name

if Deint:
    #yadif = " -vf \"yadif=0:0:0\" "
    vfs.append("yadif=0:0:0")
    #vfs.append("drawbox=x=0:y=0:w=720:h=2:color=black:t=max")
    #yadif = " -vf \"yadif=0:0:0,drawbox=x=0:y=0:w=720:h=4:color=black:t=max\" "
else : yadif = ""
if interlaced_tff:
    vfs.append("fieldorder=tff" )
if crop:
    vfs.append("crop=720:432:0:72" )
if scale:
    vfs.append("scale=720x576" )
if len(vfs) > 0:
    vfcmd = "-vf \"" + ",".join(vfs) + "\""
else: vfcmd = ""
print (vfcmd)
cmd = "ffmpeg -hide_banner -i \"" + PATH + "\" " + vfcmd 

if recode:
    
    cmd = cmd + ' -aspect "16:9" -profile:v main -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -filter:v fps=fps=25  '
    if interlaced_tff:
        cmd = cmd + " -flags +ildct+ilme -x264opts tff=1 "
    cmd = cmd + '   -crf 19  -b:a 192k  -ar 48000 -ac 2 '
else: 
    cmd = cmd + " -c:v copy " + " -af \"volume=2\" -ar 48000 " 


cmd = cmd + "\"" + EXPATH + "\""

print ( cmd )
cmdlist.append(cmd)
print ( "=-===-=-=-=" )
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

and here is the text i am getting from FFMPEG:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\\server-01\E\_NEW 
CONTENT\_Current Time\Actual Programs\PROG_Detali_80_Robopes_na_zavode_Ford_ 1017.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2020-10-17T05:10:47.000000Z
  Duration: 00:23:22.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15331 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 14999 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2020-10-17T05:10:47.000000Z
  handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
  encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-10-17T05:10:47.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
Only '-vf fps=fps=25' read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters
Only '-af (null)' read, ignoring remaining -af options: Use ',' to separate filters
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0000016645a43040] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0000016645a43040] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0000016645a43040] profile Main, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0000016645a43040] 264 - core 159 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=19.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '\\server-01\D\_RENDERED CONTENT\Current     Time\PROG_Detali_80_Robopes_na_zavode_Ford_ 1017.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.39.101
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-10-17T05:10:47.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Lavc58.73.102 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-10-17T05:10:47.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      encoder         : Lavc58.73.102 aac
frame=  217 fps= 23 q=24.0 size=   10496kB time=00:00:08.64 bitrate=9951.8kbits/s speed=0.926x
```

Comment: First you should find out how to write the ffmpeg command line by hand (without script) to get the desired output. If you know that then place an example of the command line in the question as properly formatted text.

Comment: do you mean this ' -filter:v fps=fps=25' ?

Comment: I mean the complete command line which is assembled by the script. The script prints it out before calling so you have a starting point.

Comment: ok, i hope you mean this (sorry for my stupid attempts, i am really not sure what i am doing):
added it to my post

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
cmd = cmd + ' -aspect "16:9" -profile:v main -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p '
```

to

```
cmd = cmd + ' -aspect "16:9" -profile:v main -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 '
```